# Is it possible to restrict the site search module to specific nodes?

Tags: nodes, search

I am trying to figure out a way to provide a search for a specific set of nodes. Currently it seems that the site search is not configurable in this way. Is there any way to change this functionality, or other modules that provide a search for a defined group of pages/nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these 2 modules, [Custom search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) Or [Search restrict](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_restrict). Both these modules allow you to restrict the search on specific content types